# Creating overlapped block matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, finite-element-method

I'm doing an FEM assignment using *Mathematica*.

```
(EK1 = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}) // MatrixForm
(EK2 = {{b22, b23}, {b32, b33}}) // MatrixForm
```

I don't know how the best way to create new matrix like this:

```
(K = {{a11, a12, 0}, {a21, a22 + b22, b23}, {0, b32, b33}}) // MatrixForm
```

MATLAB does it quite easily but how about *Mathematica*?

Comment: Is there a pattern to this? With the b23 where it is and not a21 on the left side of that row I can't think of one.

Comment: Anon, there are stiffness matrices. There is a coupling between elements and where they join, or overlap, the stiffness is added. But this all depends on the elements and the structure and can get very complicated.

Comment: Viet Tran, you haven't responded to Anon's comment or any of the answerers. It seems like the 0 in position `{2,1}` was a typo (as everyone seems to agree) and I've edited the question to change it to `a21`, so that the answers make sense. If you disagree, please leave a comment, else I'll assume that you are in agreement with this change.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ArrayPad`:

```
ArrayPad[EK2, {1, 0}] + ArrayPad[EK1, {0, 1}]
```

and general approach (**Edit:** overlap specification added):

```
n = {3, 3};
arrays = Array[#, n] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e}; (*arrays to work with*)

app[a1_, a2_, overlap_: 1] := With[{dim = Dimensions@a1},
                                   ArrayPad[a1, {0, n[[1]] - overlap}] + 
                                   ArrayPad[a2, Transpose@{dim - overlap, {0, 0}}]];
```

In V10+ once can use `Fold[app, arrays]` instead of `Fold[app, First@arrays,Rest@arrays]`

```
Fold[app, arrays] // MatrixForm
Fold[app[##, 2] &, arrays] // MatrixForm
Fold[app[##, 3] &, arrays] // MatrixForm
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

It is not so much general, only for constant  `n`$x$`n` set but I don't know what should be an expected result for set of arrays of different dimensions.

Comment: This has a21 where there is a zero in the OP's example. I think that might be a typo on the OP's part though.

Comment: @Anon ups, you are right. But I think it is a mistake in question :p

Comment: @Cogicero sorry, haven't got pinged earlier. What about `x[[2,3]]`?

Comment: @Cogicero Unless I'm mistaken you are using wrong syntax, you can't take element from `A` with `A[2,3]` but you have to use e.g. `Part`: `A[[2,3]]`.

Comment: @Kuba Each matrix has a value before you run the above code, but after running your code I still get the picture above with elements like a[1,1], etc. I can't use the global Matrix that I end up with, because instead of a[1,1] I should have "1" since that's row 1, col1 of a 3*3 unit matrix. Instead of a[1,2] appearing in my final answer it should be 0 since that's row 1 col 2 of a 3*3 unit matrix. Mathematica still treats the matrices as if they are arbitrary and unknown. I really hope you understand my problem now. It's a bit frustrating, and I am not sure how to GET the actual Parts to show.

Comment: This is what I am talking about. The actual matrix elements are not being fetched out of the matrix. See this image: ![sample image](http://imgur.com/PCvUkU3)

Comment: @Cogicero sorry for delay, what about `arrays = Array[Function[{i, j}, #[[i, j]]], n] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e};`

Comment: @Kuba It works well now! Thanks!! I already asked agaiin on a new question yesterday and J.M. gave me another method http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109483/38258 but I prefer this one, so now that it works for me I will be using it. I appreciate your time and effort. Wish I could up-vote this a second time.

Answer (score 6):

I gave a presentation on one (efficient) way to do it at the [2009 tech conference](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7549/).

The essence is this function:

```
matrixAssembly[ values_, pos_, dim_] := Block[{matrix, p},
  System`SetSystemOptions[ 
   "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
  matrix = SparseArray[ pos -> Flatten[ values], dim];
  System`SetSystemOptions[ 
   "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 0}];
  Return[ matrix]]
```

The option `"SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1` will add up elements at the same position.

`pos` can be computed like this:

```
pos = Flatten[ Map[ Outer[ List, #, #] &, incidents], 2];
```

Where, as an example, `incidents` of element 1 and 3 look like this:

```
incidents[[{1, 3}]]
{{23, 82, 64, 83}, {83, 82, 67, 66}}
```

In the above mentioned presentation you'll also find a method how to apply Dirichlet conditions, time integrating the system and perform some model order reduction.

Also note that since version 10.0 Mathematica has a [Finite Element Programming tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html) that shows how to use the new in V10 FEM building blocks on a low level.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use ``Internal`WithLocalSettings[]``: ``matrixAssembly[values_, pos_, dim_] := With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]}, Internal`WithLocalSettings[SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}], SparseArray[pos -> Flatten[values], dim], SetSystemOptions[spopt]]]``

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a small function once to build block-wise diagonal matrices. The zero matrix is just `0` and identity is `1`. You could use it in this case like this:

```
diagonalize[list_] := ArrayFlatten@(DiagonalMatrix[Array[x, Length@list]] /. 
    Table[x[i] -> list[[i]], {i, Length@list}]);
diagonalize[{EK1, 0}] + diagonalize[{0, EK2}] // MatrixForm
```

Oh, this is assuming that the second zero in your `K` is actually `a21`. Otherwise I don't see a pattern here.

Answer (score 2):

(* I am assuming this is meant to be a global stiffness matrix construction question and OP made type for element (2,1) *)

There are many ways to build global stiffness matrix. For your case, here is a quick hack. But if you simply google the topic of building global stiffness matrix from elements stiffness matrices, you'll find many many methods on it in finite elements books.

Notice, I gave element names inside the local stiffness as b11,b12, etc.... different than what you had to be consistent with the first matrix.

```
EK1 = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}; (*local stiffness matrix*)
EK2 = {{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}}; (*local stiffness matrix*)
n = 2; (*size of local stiffness matrix *)
locals = {EK1, EK2}; (*local stiffness matrices*)
m = Length[locals]; (*number of elements*)
r = (n m) - (m - 1); (*size of global stiffness matrix*)
K1 = Table[0, {r}, {r}];
z = 1;

Do[ K1[[z ;; z + n - 1, z ;; z + n - 1]] = locals[[i]];
    If[i > 1, K1[[z, z]] += locals[[i - 1]][[-1, -1]]];
    z = z + n - 1,
  {i, 1, m} ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For example, for 5 elements, you'll get this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I posted similar answer but @Anon has pointed out that it does not fit the question. Take a look at position {2, 1} of OP's result.

Comment: @Kuba. I see. Oh well. I just guess the OP is either wrong (made typo), or they should then say what does this pattern represents. I assumed it is a global stiffness matrix. If not, then I will also delete this answer.

Comment: I think you are right, I think so. But we can't be sure :)

Comment: @Kuba I also read at the top OP saying `FEM assignment using Mathematica.` and that is why I thought right away it is stiffness matrix. (FEM== finite elements)

Comment: Good point. I could have checked this.

Answer (score 0):

Using SparseArrays

```
EK1 = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}};
EK2 = {{b22, b23}, {b32, b33}};

{sEK1, sEK2} = 
SparseArray[#, {3, 3}, 
   0] &@(Thread[#[[2 ;;]] -> #[[1]][Sequence @@ #[[2 ;;]]], 
       2] &@(ToExpression@
       Characters@ToString[#]) & /@ (Flatten@#)) & /@ {EK1, EK2};

(sEK1 + sEK2) // Normal
```

> {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], 0}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2] + b[2, 2], b[2, 3]}, {0, 
>     b[3, 2], b[3, 3]}}

Or, more simply:

```
EK1alt = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> a11, {1, 2} -> a12, {2, 1} -> a21, {2, 2} -> a22}, {3, 3}, 0];
EK2alt = SparseArray[{{2, 2} -> b22, {2, 3} -> b23, {3, 2} -> b32, {3, 3} -> b33}, {3, 3}, 0];

(EK1alt + EK2alt) // Normal
```

> {{a11, a12, 0}, {a21, a22 + b22, b23}, {0, b32, b33}}