# How to create overlapped block matrices and simplify the result

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

This is sort of a duplicate of [Creating overlapped block matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30716), but the question wasn't fully answered since the OP never returned to clarify.

I am using [Kuba's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30717/38258) for FEM, but I have been unable to get it to work properly. The problem is that the block matrix isn't being simplified even when the arrays we are working with are known (not arbitrary). Below is sample code. I have used examples for `a`, `b` and `c`, but in my actual code the matrices are larger and much more complicated.

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
b = {{3, 2, 7}, {2, 0, 3}, {4, 1, 2}};
c = {{5, 1, 4}, {4, 5, 8}, {9, 1, 6}};

n = {3, 3};
arrays = Array[#, n] & /@ {a, b, c}; (*arrays to work with*)

app[a1_, a2_, overlap_: 1] := With[{dim = Dimensions@a1},
                                   ArrayPad[a1, {0, n[[1]] - overlap}] + 
                                   ArrayPad[a2, Transpose@{dim - overlap, {0, 0}}]];

Fold[app, First@arrays, Rest@arrays] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Result]

Notice how *Mathematica* returns Matrix[index] rather than simplifying it. How can I adjust the code and simplify this, and replace e.g. `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}[1,1]` with `1` since that is row 1, column 1 of the matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a somewhat general routine for building block diagonal matrices with overlaps:

```
blockOverlap[matList_?ArrayQ, r : (_Integer | {__Integer}) : 1] := 
     With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
          Internal`WithLocalSettings[SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" ->
                                     {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}],
          SparseArray[Sort[Flatten[MapThread[
                      ArrayRules[SparseArray[Band[{#1, #1}] -> {#2}]] &,
                      {Accumulate[Prepend[(Length /@ Most[matList]) - r, 1]], 
                       matList}]]]],
          SetSystemOptions[spopt]]]
```

OP's example:

```
blockOverlap[{a, b, c}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 8 & 12 & 2 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 1 & 4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 8 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 6 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

A slightly more general example:

```
blockOverlap[{a, b, c}, {1, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 8 & 12 & 2 & 7 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 4 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 6 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Hi J.M. Thanks a lot for your response! The coupling method you are suggesting requires you to state Band[{k,k}]-> for each array. As I said, I just simplified my FEM matrices. Each one is large, and I can't predict how many matrices there will be, so I need a solution that can apply to multiple matrices of any defined size. This is why Kuba's answer was the closest, for me. The only problem is to get it simplified. Could you please help suggest how to edit the original code, or how to turn yours into a function that admits any number of matrices of any size?

Comment: Well... 1. are all those matrices on the diagonal? 2. are they all the same size? 3. is the amount of overlap (1 in your OP) the same for all these matrices?

Comment: Yes, they are all on the diagonal (creating a tridiagonal matrix, pentadiagonal matrix, etc), all the same size and the overlap is always one (and an addition is always done at the overlap). All I need to supply to the function will be a "list" of the matrices & the size of each matrix, and it will return the sparse block matrix form (using overlaps on the diagonal).

Comment: If the diagonal blocks are all the same size and the overlap is fixed, it should not be too hard; give me a few...

Comment: This is great! Sorry I have taken so much time, but I think I found a bug, and I'm unsure how to debug it. Using 4*4 matrices (one of my test cases) and `a = {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 8}, {7, 8, 9, 2}, {5, 2, 4, 3}}; b = {{3, 2, 7, 1}, {2, 0, 3, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 5}, {7, 8, 6, 2}}; c = {{5, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 5, 8, 1}, {9, 1, 6, 2}, {8, 5, 3, 2}};` and your function for blockOverlap (default overlap of 1), notice that the overlap of a and b should be 6 (i.e. 3 plus 3). Rather it is 3.

Comment: Fixed (had used `Union[]` instead of `Sort[]`); try it now.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton!!