# Associating values of two matrices through sum

Tags: matrix, associations

I have the following code:

```
k12 = {{6.08, 1.52, -6.08, -1.52},{1.52, 380448.03, -1.52, -380448.03}, {-6.08, -1.52, 6.08, 1.52},{-1.52, -380448.03, 1.52, 380448.03}}

k14 = ({{3.84, 2.56, -3.84, -2.56},{2.56, 1.70, -2.56, -1.70},{-3.84, -2.56, 3.84, 2.56},{-2.56, -1.70, 2.56, 1.70}})

kglobal = ({{k12[[1, 1]], k12[[2, 1]], k12[[3, 1]], k12[[4, 1]], 0, 0, 0, 0},{k12[[1, 2]], k12[[2, 2]], k12[[3, 2]], k12[[4, 2]], 0, 0, 0, 0},{k12[[1, 3]], k12[[2, 3]], k12[[3, 3]], k12[[4, 3]], 0, 0, 0, 0},{k12[[1, 4]], k12[[2, 4]], k12[[3, 4]], k12[[4, 4]], 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}) + ({{k14[[1, 1]], k14[[2, 1]], 0, 0, 0, 0, k14[[3, 1]], k14[[4, 1]]},{k14[[1, 2]], k14[[2, 2]], 0, 0, 0, 0, k14[[3, 2]], k14[[4, 2]]},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{k14[[1, 3]], k14[[2, 3]], 0, 0, 0, 0, k14[[3, 3]], k14[[4, 3]]},{k14[[1, 4]], k14[[2, 4]], 0, 0, 0, 0, k14[[3, 4]], k14[[4, 4]]}})
```

[image]

The value `k12[[1.1]]` should go to `kglobal[[1.1]]` and so forth until `k12[[4.4]]` be `kglobal[[4.4]]`.

However the value `k14[[1.1]]` must be added to the value already exists for `k12[[1.1]]` modifying `kglobal[[1.1]]`.

Another problem is that the value of `k14[[3, 1]]` should go to `kglobal[[7.1]]` and not for `kglobal[[3.1]]`, that is, there is a breach of sequences.

How can I create this kind of association?

Note that for any result I needed to write the matrices manually, so nothing automated.

I was thinking in to use Insert, Association, or another command that I could automate this task.

Comment: Is this related? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30716/5478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think try to create a zero-matrix and add your matrix on it will be helpful, just like the following code shows.

```
In[22]:= kglobal2 = Module[{sum = ConstantArray[0, {8, 8}]},
  sum[[1 ;; 4, 1 ;; 4]] += k12;
  sum[[{1, 2, -2, -1}, {1, 2, -2, -1}]] += k14\[Transpose];
  sum
  ]

Out[22]= {{9.92, 4.08, -6.08, -1.52, 0, 0, -3.84, -2.56}, {4.08, 
  380450., -1.52, -380448., 0, 0, -2.56, -1.7}, {-6.08, -1.52, 6.08, 
  1.52, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1.52, -380448., 1.52, 380448., 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-3.84, -2.56, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 3.84, 2.56}, {-2.56, -1.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.56, 1.7}}

In[23]:= kglobal2 == kglobal

Out[23]= True
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Because I had not idea how could I enter the values in the correct position. With `sum[[1 ;; 4, 1 ;; 4]] += k12` and `sum[[{1, 2, -2, -1}, {1, 2, -2, -1}]] += k14` I can do this easily.

Answer (score 2):

Will this a-bit-complex code fullfill your need?

```
arrayinsert[mat_, x_, y_] := 
 With[{pre = ArrayFlatten@List@Riffle[#, Unevaluated@ConstantArray[0, {Length@#[[1]], x}]] & /@ mat}, 
  ArrayFlatten[List /@ Riffle[pre, Unevaluated@ConstantArray[0, {y, Length@pre[[1, 1]]}]]]]

ArrayPad[k12, {0, 4}] + arrayinsert[Partition[k14, {2, 2}], 4, 4]
```

The key of this piece of code is the function `arrayinsert`, check the following code and figure and you'll realize how to use this function:

```
arrayinsert[Partition[ConstantArray[1, {9, 9}], {3, 3}], 2, 2] // ArrayPlot

arrayinsert[Transpose[Internal`PartitionRagged[Transpose@#, Range@4] & /@ 
    Internal`PartitionRagged[ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}], Range@4]], 2, 4] // ArrayPlot
```

[image: illus]

Comment: His answer was incredible. It was like a spell. But for my level of knowledge I am not prepared to this.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho Thanks for your appreciation! I'm glad that I can help you. :)